# Property observers Swift 4

Tags: swift, property-observer

```
struct Kitchen // Coordinator 

{
   var foodItems = [FoodItem] () // Collection of FoodItem objects.
   var wastedItems = [WastedItem]() // Collection of WastedItem 
   var totalSpend = Double()
   var currentSpend = Double()
   var weeklyHouseholdFoodBudget = Double()
   var wastageCost = Double()

   init(aTotal:Double,aCurrent:Double,aBudget:Double,aWastage:Double)
    {
    self.totalSpend = aTotal
    self.currentSpend = aCurrent
    self.weeklyHouseholdFoodBudget = aBudget
    self.wastageCost = aWastage
    }

struct FoodItem : Equatable 
{
    var itemName = String()
    var itemQuantity = Double()
    var dateOfUse = String()
    var unitOfMeasurement = String()

    init(aName:String,aQuantity:Double,aDateOfUse:String,aUnit:String) 
    {
     self.itemName = aName
     self.itemQuantity = aQuantity
     self.dateOfUse = aDateOfUse
     self.unitOfMeasurement = aUnit
    }

   mutating func listFoodItems() 
     {
       for item in foodItems
       {
        print("Item Name:", item.getName(),",",
              "Qunatity:",item.getItemQuantity(),",", 
              "Unit:",item.getUnitOfMeasurement(),",",
              "Date of use:",item.getDateOfUse())
        }
      }

     mutating func removeFoodItem(aFood:FoodItem) 
      {
       if let anIndex = foodItems.index(of: aFood)
       {
       foodItems.remove(at: anIndex)
       print(aFood.getName(),"Has been removed")
       }
      }

      mutating func useFood(aFoodItem:inout  FoodItem,inputQty:Double) 

      {
        if (aFoodItem.getItemQuantity()) - (inputQty) <= 0
        {
         self.removeFoodItem(aFood: aFoodItem)
        }
         else
        {
         aFoodItem.useFoodItem(aQty: inputQty)                 
        }
      }
```

***Updated****
The issue I am having is when I use a func listFoodItems() the updated attribute itemQuantity does not change. I would like to know how to update the collection so when I call the func listFoodItems() it displays value changes.

The removal is ok, when the func runs the collection removes the object. 
The issue must be because I am using for item in foodItems to display, I need to reload it with updated values before I do this?

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: Which property is not reflecting? And can you show more of your code like removeFoodItem, useFoodItem, etc? Also please format your code properly so that people can easily read it.

Comment: Sorry  Rakesha Shastri, I'm a bit of a newbie. I have included more code and tried to make it easier to read. Thanks.

Comment: No worries. You say that listFoodItems does not update list quantity. But from what i see, it is a method just for displaying. So you should use either of the other two functions first to change the item quantity before calling list food items?

Comment: Hi Rakesha, that’s correct. If i create a FoodItem I.e food1 then use aKitchen.addToList() it simply calls foodItem.append(food1). But if I change itemQuantity by using a setter or useFood(), I need to update the [foodItem] list. Basically, it’s a food inventory that should be updated as and when people use food. Obviously, if i clear the list and re-append the object the value changes are visable, but there must be an easier way?? Thanks

Comment: I’m thinking that I could write a upadateFoodItem(food1), find its index, remove it and re- append at same index, but that index wouldn’t exist anymore?? Any ideas?

Comment: If by removing and reappend, you mean put it back in the same position, you can use `insert(at:)` method. However your question is still not clear.

Comment: If food1 for instance is  6 "Eggs", then aKitchen.useFood(food1:3) changes food1 to 3 "Eggs" I want the aKitchen.listFoodItems() to display the change. Removal part is fine, I just would like to display the attribute value change. I can't use for item in foodItems if item == food1, item.setQuantity because it is a let by default. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Property observers are used on properties. 
The simplest example of a property observer.

```
class Foo {
    var bar: String = "Some String" {
        didSet {
            print("did set value", bar)
        }
    }
}
```

Now if you want to display some changes, you will need your own code in didSet method in order to do that. For example call reloadData().